# Typescript: force exclude file even if it was imported

Tags: typescript, import

I want to exclude a *.ts file from compilation by adding it into "exclude" property in tsconfig.json. Although if I do import that file somewhere in the code it ignores the exclusion and compiles it anyway. How to force TS to exclude this file?

../

../must_be_excluded.ts

../index.ts

Using import

```
//index.ts
import {some_stuff} from "./must_be_excluded"
```

Tsconfig settings

```
//tsconfig.json
{
   "compilerOptions": {...},
   "exclude": ["./must_be_excluded.ts"]
}
```

I see must_be_excluded.js anyway!

Comment: More data is needed. Why do you want to exclude? Any situation I see which would require this can be solved with moving some code to another file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well it'll have to be, if you're importing and using that function in anywhere that needs it, it'll need to be compiled into JavaScript.

How would it work otherwise? Everything will run smoothly until that particular function call.

Try removing the `import` declaration and you'll notice it should respect the fact it's excluded.

Comment: Its contents could be treated as `any`.